# Asymptote reach of two curves

Tags: geometry

Is it correct that two hyperbolas which tend to the same asymptote from two different sides reach each other faster than exponentially?

Comment: No, it isn't. These are algebraic functions, no exponential is involved.

Comment: I mean would two exponential functions reach each other faster? I would say no, because the cant get vertical in a finit time. A hyperbola can.

Comment: I think you should then rephrase your question, explaining in more detail what you really mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking (a diagram might help), but recall that an asymptote is *never* reached by the function which has that line as an asymptote. Therefore, two functions which approach the same asymptote but from different sides will **never** meet. They will never reach each other.

Comment: If i had 1/(t-1)^2 and 1/(t-1)^3 they both would reach their vertical asymptotes in a finit time, wouldnt they?

Comment: For $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$, the vertical asymptote is $x=1$. If that function "reaches it in finite time," as you say, then that means there is a value of $x$ such that $f(x)=1$. I challenge you to find that number. Spoiler: there isn't one that isn't called *infinity*. But since we can't graph infinity, we have to state that $f(x)$ will never intersect the asymptote. There is no time that is finite in which to reach the asymptote. This is the definition for all asymptotes, not just for this function.